# Salesforce support for Scripting languages in Visualforce pages embedded in Service Console

Tags: visualforce, console

I had an issue with a Visualforce page embedded as a tab in the Service Console. I created a case with Salesforce support to help me with the issue as it was working prior the recent Chrome upgrade.

Salesforce developer support came back and reviewed the page, but then said that they will not be able to continue support due to Javascript running on the page. They advised for us to remove the Javascript first and then re-engage them again.

Is this truly the case for SF support? If so, is it in the generic Master Services Agreement? Would appreciate if anyone in the community can feedback and maybe show a link to the MSA where this can be found, as I tried in vain to find anything in the net.
Thanks for your usual assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic ("Core") Support does not support Apex, JavaScript, Aura, Lightning Web Components, etc. They can forward the case to the appropriate team only if it is standard functionality that is broken (e.g. if a lookup field in Visualforce does not work), and then, only if no custom JavaScript is involved. Premier Support includes "Developer Support", which allows snippets of custom code to be diagnosed and fixed, up to a couple hundred lines worth of code. You'll want to read the Knowledge Article titled [Premier and Premier+ Success: Developer Support](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315327&type=1&mode=1) for more information.